# How do I enable word wrap in Linqpad?

Tags: linqpad

How do I enable word wrap in Linqpad's text editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now there's no option for word wrap in LINQPad. You can register a request [here](http://linqpad.uservoice.com).

---

As of [Linqpad Beta v4.48](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx), word-wrap is now supported. Check Edit / Preferences

Comment: http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3278225-word-wrap-in-text-editor